# End Thread^ which isn't completed

Tags: .net, multithreading, c++-cli

I have two threads within an event in my C++ GUI application (Visual Studio). The function has to run some code, but I want to end the thread when a specified time is elapsed. The thread I have made is:

```
ThreadStart^ oThread = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::ThreadMethod);
Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread(oThread);
newThread->Start();
```

How can I end the thread? Because what I tried ends with an exception.

Comment: Beware: This is very dangerous, especially if that thread runs any unmanaged code.

Comment: It is running managed code. But do you know some way to archieve this?

Comment: Use `Abort()`, with caution.

Comment: I think you need another language tag. This isn't C++ code.

Comment: That's nearly impossible to do in a robust way without the thread's cooperation. Let the thread terminate itself after a certain time _and_ when _it_ knows it is safe to do so (see @user7116 [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18744677/21567) for an example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is nothing preventing `MyForm::ThreadMethod` from tracking its own time spent, why not integrate the timing into your threaded work?

```
void ThreadMethod
{
    Int64 watchdog = 1000L * 5L * 60L; // 5 minutes
    System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch^ sw
        = System::Diagnostics::Stopwatch::StartNew();

    while (sw->ElapsedMilliseconds < watchdog
        && otherCondition)
    {
         // do your work here
    }
}
```

Comment: Can somebody tell me how I can stop a thread from another thread, when I have three threads in my program?

Comment: You could always make `otherCondition` a flag variable of sorts which another thread could set to `false`.

Comment: I now start thwo threads under a event button, for each thread I have a thread method just like this: `this->Invoke(gcnew MethodInvoker(this, &MyForm::nameMethodToExecute));`. One thread has a timer and the other thread the executing code. When the timer elapsed I want to close the other thread. How can I make it possible, because `thread->Abort()` isn't the right way and gives an exception.

Comment: It has to do with some condition, but I wrote my code some other way and works the way you suggested. Thanks!